# populate data from database into select dropbox

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have a select box which needs to fetch from the database.

**view blade:**

```
<select class="form-control" name="service_type" id="service_type" data-parsley-required="true">
@foreach ($service as $sn) 

{
 <option value="">dd($sn)</option>
}
@endforeach
</select>
```

**controller:**

```
public function index()
{
    $service = DB::select('select service_type from services');

    return view("service",['service'=>$service]);
}
```

I am getting an error like

> Undefined variable: service (View: /home/devadmin/.config/composer/vendor/laravel/installer/serenseprj/resources/views/package.blade.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code as the references. Hope you have service model.

```
$services= Service::pluck('name', 'id');
return view('services', compact('services'));
```

then in view file you can use laravel collevtives like.

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-6">
{!! Form::label('service_id', 'service Id:') !!}
{!! Form::select('service_id', $services, null, ['class' => 'form-control'])!!}
</div>
```

you can use this too. in you blade file

```
<select name="service " id="service " class="form-control">
<option value=""> -- Select One --</option>
@foreach ($services as $service )
    <option value="{{ $service->id }}">{{ $service->name }}</option>
@endforeach
```

Comment: mine do not use this type of form can you change it to normal html form

Comment: i used but getting error Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Service' not found

Answer (score 0):

You can use Eloquent instead of doing this

```
$service = DB::select('select service_type from services');
```

Using Eloquent,

```
$services = ModelName::pluck('name', 'id')->get();
```

You can pass the variable to the targeted view like below:

```
return view('view_name', ['variable_name' => $variable]);
```

And, you can access the variable name like below

```
<select class="form-control" name="service_type" id="service_type" data-parsley-required="true">
@foreach ($variable_name as $var)
{
 <option value="{{$var->id}}">{{$var->name}}</option>
}
@endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: it is showing error Undefined variable: service (View:

Comment: i am getting error like Trying to get property 'service_type' of non-object

Comment: @chaitra there may be a case where the object is empty. so, that can be the reason for this error.